# Flickering light after installing a ceiling fan

Tags: electrical, light

I was installing a ceiling fan and needed to drill a new hole in the top plate so I could run the appropriate wire for the new switch.  As I was drilling I knocked the 12/2 Romex going to my ceiling fan.  I cut out the bad portion of Romex and spliced in a new part and completed my install.  Days later I now have a flickering light in another bedroom in my house that is on a different circuit all together.  I'm wondering if this is just happenstance or if I need to replace that 12/2 Romex I spliced with a whole wire.  To the best of my ability I didn't notice any other damaged wires that were affected.  Would this be a switch or issue at the flickering light itself?  This is a fairly newer house.  2015.  Please help.

Comment: What happens when you drill in power cable ? A massive short, with sparks and smoke, flash of light, blown fuse ? shocked human ?

Comment: What type of light?  Splices must be in a junction box that is accessible.  The flickering could have started with a power surge/rapid change, or just started at the same time just because.

Comment: It's hard to say why the light is flickering.  If it is an LED, they sometimes do decide to flicker even in perfect conditions.  If it is flickering constantly that has to be addressed.

Comment: The splice currently isn't in a junction box as I didn't know that was necessary.  I am planning on running a new line for the damages Romex soon just to ensure nothing bad.Could the two circuits share a neutral wire and that is affecting it?I did notice today when I turned a ceiling fan on in the flickering room (different circuit) than the damaged Romex, it makes the flickering light dim a little when I switch.   The flickering isn't all the time. Just intermittent, and something the light will go completely out for a while and then then back on.So it's not always the standard flickering.